# laravel using a primary key in another table as input in another table

Tags: laravel-5

I have two tables Vehicles table and applications table, I need when a user makes an application, the vehicle_id is automatically inserted into the applications table so that I can track the vehicle the user has applied for... I have created the relationship between the two tables as follows:

> In my application model

```html
 
 public function vehicle(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Martin\Models\Vehicle');
  }
```

> In my Vehicle model

```html
public function application(){

return  $this->hasMany('Martin\Models\Application');
}
```

my migrations for vehicle applications where I want the vehicle_id inserted are as follows:

```html
  public function up()
    {
      Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->integer('admin_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->integer('vehicle_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->integer('application_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->string('acronym');
          $table->string('destination');
          $table->integer('Number_of_days_hired');
          $table->string('vehicle_registration_number');
          $table->timestamp('departure_date_and_time');
          $table->boolean('approved')->unsigned()->nullable();
          $table->timestamp("created_at")->useCurrent();
          $table->timestamp("updated_at")->useCurrent();
          $table->foreign('user_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('users')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
          $table->foreign('admin_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('admins')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
          });
          $table->foreign('vehicle_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('vehicles')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
          });
    }
```

how do I get the values into the vehicle_id column?

```html
Application::create([
            'user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
      'vehicle_id'=>,
            'acronym'=>$request->input('acronym'),
            'destination'=>$request->input('destination'),
```

I have this in my application form

```html
  <form class="form-vertical" role="form" action="{{route('application.make',['id'=>Auth::user()->id])}}" method="POST">
                                               {{csrf_field()}}
                                 <input type="hidden" name="vehicle_id" value="{{Vehicle::with('application')->id}}">
                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                      <div class="form-group label-floating {{$errors->has('acronym') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                        <label class="control-label">Group Acronym</label>
                                        <select name="acronym" class="form-control">
                                           <option>Select Group Acronym</option><!--selected by default-->
                                           @foreach($users as $user)
                                               <option value="{{$user->acronym}}">
                                                   {{$user->description}}
                                               </option>
                                           @endforeach
                                      </select>
                                @if($errors->has('acronym'))
                                     <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('acronym')}}</span>
                                @endif()

                                    </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                          <div class="form-group label-floating {{$errors->has('destination') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                            <label class="control-label">Destination</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="destination" class="form-control" required>
                                            @if($errors->has('destination'))
                                                 <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('destination')}}</span>
                                            @endif()

                                          </div>
                                          </div>

                                </div><!--ends first -row-->



                                                <div class="row">

                                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                    <div class="form-group label-floating {{$errors->has('Number_of_days_hired') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                                      <label class="control-label">Number Of Days Hired</label>
                                              <select  name="Number_of_days_hired" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                              </select>

                                              @if($errors->has('Number_of_days_hired'))
                                                   <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('Number_of_days_hired')}}</span>
                                              @endif()

                                                  </div>
                                                        </div>

                                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                        <div class="form-group label-floating {{$errors->has('vehicle_registration_number') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                                          <label class="control-label">Vehicle</label>
                                                          <select name="vehicle_registration_number" class="form-control">
                                                             <option>Select Vehicle</option><!--selected by default-->
                                                             @foreach($vehicles as $vehicle)
                                                                 <option value="{{$vehicle->vehicle_registration_number}}">
                                                                     {{ $vehicle->description }}
                                                                 </option>
                                                             @endforeach
                                                        </select>
                                                  @if($errors->has('vehicle_registration_number'))
                                                       <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('vehicle_registration_number')}}</span>
                                                  @endif()

                                                      </div>
                                                        </div>



                                                              <div class="col-sm-4">
                                                                    <div class="form-group label-floating {{$errors->has('departure_time') ? ' has-error' : ''}}">
                                                                      <label class="control-label">Departure Date and Time</label>
                                                                      <input type="datetime-local"  name="departure_date_and_time" class="form-control" required>
                                                                      @if($errors->has('departure_time'))
                                                                           <span class="help-block">{{$errors->first('departure_time')}}</span>
                                                                      @endif()

                                                                    </div>
                                                                    </div>



                                                </div><!--ends second row-->
```

My application is a transport management system or bus reservation system where when user makes an application his tranport is reserved

Comment: You can store `vehicle_id` in form as `<input type="hidden" name="vehicle_id" value="SOME_VALUE">` and then use it as `$request->input('vehicle_id')`

Comment: Thanks @Jozef Am using the technique you have given me... but the value how do I retrieve it?.. any idea

Comment: I'dont know what exactly you want to do. `$request->input('vehicle_id')` this is how you retrieve value from POST request. But you have to pass this value(vehicle_id) in to the form. I don't know how your form looks like.

Comment: Well I want to get a relationship between the vehicle so that the vehicle which was applied by a user in the bus management system can be excluded for other users to apply and is not visible to them... bythewei am a newbie in laravel... could you kindly advice on the same...

Comment: Ok, so you can make `select` in html form with all vehicles and when user chooses one, you send this value(vehicle_id) with form to server to handle it and then you can access to this value by `$request->input('vehicle_id')`

Comment: I really don't get what you mean here,,, can you kindly elaborate,,, my apologies for any inconvinience